# Why is Captain Kirk's brother called "Sam" in Star Trek: Strange New Worlds?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-strange-new-worlds

Why does everyone on SNW call Captain Kirk's brother Sam when it is explicitly stated in TOS that Captain Kirk is the only one who calls him Sam?

Comment: My own head-canon is that this a way to suggest that James Kirk doesn't know as much about his brother's life as he thinks he does.

Comment: the producers have stated multiple times that they are fine with "bending" canon in relation to TOS. If you think canon to TOS is important, imo, it's best to consider SNW as a new timeline and then it's fine

Comment: @NKCampbell It's probably not a good idea to think of SNW as a new timeline because, as far we know, it's definitely not. Slight differences don't justify just calling the whole thing a whole different timeline. And SNW, compared to other _Trek_ shows, has stayed as close to canon as possible while still maintaining its modernity.

Comment: Kirk's middle name/initial changes, so why not how people address his brother.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry - thinking of it as a new timeline is best for my own mental health :) *cough* *gorn* *cough* *t'pring* *cough* *kirk*

Comment: @NKCampbell That completely makes sense. As you've reminded me, they broke canon plenty of times.